# does silverlight isolated storage work on citrix & remote desktops?

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage, citrix

I have a requirement to store minimum user data from silverlight app. The requirement is to have this runnning in a citrix or a remote desktop session (each user has a seperate login for remote desktop).

Since I donot have a citrix setup with me, I would need responses if someone has tested this isolated storage in citrix environment.